# Remove an entire hset from Redis (Jedis), having issues since it just won't remove

Tags: redis, set, pipeline, jedis

pipe.hset(uuid, "name", "Archie");

This is an example of how I am using the hset. There are about 10 other attributes (name, age, etc.).

I am trying to remove the entire hset, e.g. remove uuid so it is no longer a key (is key the right term?).

I have tried removing each element individually through a pipeline;

```
for (String s : profileData)  {
                pipe.hdel("profile@" + uuid.toString(), s);
           }
```

But firstly, this has time complexity O(n) and so can be more efficient and secondly it isn't actually working for me, as the keys are still present (think this could be my own coding fault).

I've seen questions asking for a hdelall function and I know that one doesn't exist.

I also tried using,

```
pipe.del(uuid);
```

But this does nothing - so obviously I'm using it incorrectly. I assumed it would just delete the whole hset but it doesn't, it must be used to delete a single value instead? I'm unsure.

So my question boils down to;
How can I efficiently remove an entire hset from Redis, **using Jedis**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your code looks like, but I did this quick test and it worked for me as expected.

```
    import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
    import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;
    import redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline;

    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.Set;       

public class TestRedisDelete {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestRedisDelete redis = new TestRedisDelete();
        Pipeline p = redis.jedisPool.getResource().pipelined();
        p.hset("h1", "f", "v");
        p.hset("h2", "f", "v");
        p.hset("h3", "f", "v");
        p.del("h1");
        p.sync();

        Set<String> keys = redis.jedisPool.getResource().keys("*");
        System.out.println(keys);
    }

    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "127.0.0.1", 6379);

    private JedisPoolConfig buildPoolConfig() {
        final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(4);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());
        poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
        poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
        return poolConfig;
    }
}
```

Output: [h2, h3]

Answer (score 0):

How about using the delete method of JEDIS

```
jedis.del(uuid);
```

Check this [link](https://gist.github.com/allwefantasy/3615650) for more details

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work. I'm going to try again. But I was thinking, maybe it's because I'm grabbing a few Responses through the pipeline (a Response is the object returned from a GET method in the pipeline), and then deleting the keys which the responses refer to in the same pipe. Perhaps that isn't allowed as the data is being fetched and then deleted in one pipeline.sync() 'cycle'. Any clues?